# How does numpy generate samples from a beta distribution?

Tags: distributions, random-generation, numpy

`numpy` lets you generate random samples from a beta distribution (or any other arbitrary distribution) with this API:

```
samples = np.random.beta(a,b, size=1000)
```

What is this doing beneath the hood? Inverse Transform Sampling?

Comment: I think you can find your answer here, https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/c90d7c94fd2077d0beca48fa89a423da2b0bb663/numpy/random/mtrand/distributions.c.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The code for `numpy.random.beta` is found at [legacy-distributions.c](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/9ee262b5bf89e8c866a507e4d62b78532361adc2/numpy/random/src/legacy/legacy-distributions.c) at the time of this writing.

1. When $a$ and $b$ are both 1 or less, then Jöhnk's beta generator is used (see page 418 of *Non-Uniform Random Variate Generation*), with a modification to avoid divisions by zero.
2. Otherwise, it uses the formula $X/(X+Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are gamma($a$) and gamma($b$), respectively, generated by the legacy gamma generator.  (In general, the gamma generator uses Marsaglia and Tsang's algorithm [2000] unless the parameter is less than 1.)

Notice that `numpy.random.*` functions (including `numpy.random.beta`) became legacy functions since NumPy 1.17 introduced a new system for pseudorandom number generation (see the [NumPy RNG Policy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/neps/nep-0019-rng-policy.rst)).  Thus, the implementation of `numpy.random.beta` is not expected to change for as long as `numpy.random.*` functions are still present in NumPy, and the beta generator used in the new RNG system may differ from the one presented here.

In fact, at the time of this writing, the new generator is slightly different from the legacy generator (see [distributions.c](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/5cae51e794d69dd553104099305e9f92db237c53/numpy/random/src/distributions/distributions.c) at the time of this writing), and one of the reasons for introducing the new RNG system is to allow the non-uniform random generators to be improved without having to maintain backward compatibility.

REFERENCES:

- Marsaglia, G., Tsang, W.W., "A simple method for generating gamma variables", *ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software* 26(3), 2000.

Comment: These are some interesting facts about `numpy.random.binomial` and `numpy.random.*` overall, but I don't think the answers the question. What method does `numpy.random.beta` use to generate random values?

Comment: @Sycorax: I already answered it: It uses Jöhnk's algorithm for a and b both 1 or less, and otherwise generates a beta random number with two gamma random numbers.

Comment: Thank you for editing your post to clarify how `numpy.random.beta` works.

Comment: ah yes, I saw that Gamma trick on the bottom Beta's wikipedia page and was able to sample from a Beta using the ratio of Gammas. Is there a name for this technique? Then, the next logical question is how to generate samples from a Gamma. You answered that w/ the Marsalglia and Tsang's algorithm called Ziggurat.

Comment: No, it's not the Ziggurat algorithm, but an algorithm from 2000 called "A simple method for generating gamma variables".